# Select distinct but show constant SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with approximately 3 MM rows. I am selecting distinct values however, the value that needs to be displayed is going to be a constant 1. I am not sure how to do this.

```
select distinct ID 
from CSG_Customer
```

This is going into a larger table and want to be able to use the value rather than a not null grouping.

Comment: post sample data and output

Comment: your question is unclear, describe or clarify more (i.e. provide also sample data and expected output)

Comment: I dont get it... the result will be always 1 or...?

Comment: Do you try output a character '1'?

Comment: you want to show only one value from your table?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `group by` instead of `distinct`:

```
select
 1
from CSG_Customer
group by ID
```

However, that doesn't seem all that useful. Are you really looking for distinct IDs? Aren't your IDs unique? :D